# Disable selecting another cell while in Edit Mode datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is it possible to disable users from selecting a cell while in Edit Mode? Because I am updating a database based on the users's selected cell.

I am having a problem in saving whenever a user selects new cell while in edit mode because the value changes before it tries to save the data.

here is my code:

```
  Private Sub datagridview1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles datagridview1.CellEndEdit
    command.commandtext = "Update person SET name = '"& datagridview1.selectedcells(0).value.toString &"' WHERE ID = " & TODetails.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value & ""
    command.executeNonQuery
end sub
```

Comment: You want to modify what is the standard behaviour in any piece of software. If you start editing something but then change your mind, you might exit the given field (e.g., by pressing ESC or by clicking somewhere else) by being completely sure that no information will be stored. Your software should be intuitively utilised by any user (on account of how all the remaining software in the world works, as described above). That is: update the database only when the changes in the cell have been validated (e.g., the user pressed enter) and by relying on other event (e.g., `CellValueChanged`).

Comment: can you give me a sample? because I don't have any idea how to combine those events.

Comment: You don't need to combine anything, just rely on other event (on one not caring about what happens when a cell is editted at all; just about what happens when the new values has been validated by the user). Put the contents you are showing, which BTW are improvable (have you heard about something called SQL injection? -> your code might have this problem), in the `CellEndEdit` event inside another event like `CellValueChanged`. You don't need to use `CellEndEdit` for anything.